# JPA many to one/one to many query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I would like to create JPA query based on this tables

```
**category**                                              

(pk)CategoryID int (10)
category VARCHAR (45)         

**templatecat**

(pk/fk)templateId int(10)       
(pk/fk)categoryId int (10) 

 **template**

(pk)templateId int (10)
template madiumtext
```

I also have a "tempaltecat" table that holds foreign keys for category and template table.I`d like to create query that finds all templates in template table based on category and vice versa.

Here is my table mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "templatecat", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "categoryId", unique = true) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "templateId") })

private Set<Template> template;

@Entity
@Table(name = "template")
@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinTable(name = "templatecat", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "templateId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "categoryId") })

private Category category;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a @ManyToMany relationship,

Instead of using @OneToMany and @ManyToMany, you can use the following configuration:

In Category class:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "templatecat", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "categoryId", unique = true) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "templateId") })
private Set<Template> templates;
```

In Template class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "template")
@ManyMany(optional = true, mappedBy="templates");
private Set<Category> categories;
```

If you want to see all Templates of a given Category, the query would be:

```
select o.templates from Category o where o.id = ?
```

The reverse works as well (all Categories from a Template)

```
select o.categories from Template o where o.id = ?
```

Hope it has helped you.

Comment: I think that my relation is correct because one category can have many templates but one template cannot have more than one category.However I think that my question was a bit unclear,I'd like to find all templates on given category name.

Comment: so, why don't you use a `@OneToMany` (in category) and a `@ManyToOne` (in template) relationship? In this way, you will not need an intermediate table, and the query would be: `select o.templates from Category o where o.name = ?`